# Confusion about irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers

Irrational numbers is defined as something that cannot be expressed as a fraction .

Now I got a question . So is "120%" an integer or irrational number ?

Do I take 120% as 1.2 or just 120% as an integer (ignoring the % sign)

Comment: What does it have to do with irrationals anyway?

Comment: $\%$ just means $1/100$.

Answer (score 0):

$120\%$ means a scalar factor of ${6\over5}\in{\mathbb Q}$ when applied to real quantities, or quantities referred to a unit, like dollars. But nobody would declare that the solution of the equation $5x-6=0$ is $120\%$.